# How to call an object using post data from a list of objects in Django?

Tags: django, list, post, python-2.7, filter

Django 1.6/Python 2.7.

I am making an app where the user votes on a 'citizen' from a group of citizen objects, and this citizen becomes the best citizen.  A citizen is only eligible to become 'best citizen' if he/she has 3 or more 'votes'.  I add citizens and votes in the admin, so we won't deal with that here.  These are my models:

best_app/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    can_best = models.BooleanField(False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Best_Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    citizen = models.OneToOneField(Citizen)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am running into problems in the choose_best view, where the chosen citizen should be narrowed down by primary key.  I can't call get() on a list of objects, but this seems to me what I should do.  I have also tried filter to narrow down the view and the syntax is incorrect.

```
from best_app.models import Citizen, Best_Citizen
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404

def index(request):

    citizens = Citizen.objects.all()
 #   citizens = get_list_or_404(Citizen)
    for citizen in citizens: 
        if citizen.votes >= 3:
            citizen.can_best = True
            citizen.save()

    return render(request, 'best_app/index.html', {'citizens':citizens})

def detail(request, citizen_id):

    try:
        citizen = Citizen.objects.get(pk=citizen_id)
    except Citizen.DoesNotExist:
        print "raise Http404"
    return render(request, 'best_app/detail.html', {'citizen':citizen})
 #   return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % citizen.name)

def choose_best(request):

    best_candidates = get_list_or_404(Citizen, can_best=True)       # narrow down the candidates for best citizen to those with >= 3 votes

    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            selected_choice = best_candidates.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Citizen.DoesNotExist):

            return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:   
            Best_Citizen.objects.all().delete()                 # Current best citizen is deleted to make way for new best citizen
            new_best = Best_Citizen(citizen=selected_choice)    
            new_best.save()
            return render(request, 'best_app/index.html', {'new_best':new_best})

    else:
        return render(request, 'best_app/choose_best.html', {'best_candidates':best_candidates})
```

I get the error message "List attribute has no attribute get".  How can I select the chosen 'best candidate' by primary key, if filter and get do not work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation for `get_list_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) states, it casts its result to a list. That's no good if you want to filter it further: so don't use that shortcut.

```
 best_candidates = Citizen.objects.filter(can_best=True)
```

Comment: He could also do this `selected_choice = get_object_or_404(Citizen, pk=request.POST['choice'])` instead of `selected_choice = best_candidates.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])` (and leave the get_list_or_404 part alone)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman 
Filter was the first thing I tried, and I kept getting the error 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.  Upon further inspection, this is associated with selected_choice = best_candidates.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])